# .slideToggle() is being triggered many times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tumblr, slidetoggle

I'm trying to create a Tumblr theme in which the links and post information slide in when you click a + sign. (My test blog is at http://noitsnotitsnotokay.tumblr.com/)

I'm quite the begginner at JavaScript, but I was able to work it out for a links menu with the following code:

```
<span class="btn">+</span>
<ul class="lks">
<!-- various links are here -->
</ul>

<script>
$("ul.lks").hide();
$("span.btn").click(function () {
  $("ul.lks").slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>
```

But I also have a piece of code that applies to all posts, for the post information. I used nearly the same code, but, as you can probably see, it slides in and out various times.

```
<div class="pstinfo">
    <!-- info is here -->
</div>
<span class="plsign">+</span>

<script>
$("div.pstinfo").hide();
$("span.plsign").click(function () {
  $("div.pstinfo").slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>
```

It seems that the button's order and the way I name the classes in the JavaScript isn't changing much...any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If you you don't want to open all the '.pstinfo' elements when you click on '.plsign', just the related one, try this code:

HTML:

```
 <div class='parentContainer'> <!--put your elements in a parent Container -->
        <div class='info'>
            Info 1
        </div>   
        <div class='plsign'>
            + Open
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class='parentContainer'>
        <div class='info'>
            Info 2
        </div>   
        <div class='plsign'>
            + Open
        </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class='parentContainer'>
        <div class='info'>
            Info 3
        </div>   
        <div class='plsign'>
            + Open
        </div> 
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(".plsign").on('click',function () 
 {   
    $(this).parent().find('.info').slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

Link to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SFMTB/24/)

Comment: I tried adding that, but it seems that it works on every other div, for some reason?

Comment: Try with .each and .click http://jsfiddle.net/SFMTB/29/ . You also have more then one div with the same id :'outer' . Id must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

code block 01

```
<span class="btn">+</span>
<ul class="lks">
<!-- various links are here -->
</ul>

<script>
$("ul.lks").hide();
$("span.btn").click(function () {
  $("ul.lks").stop().slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>
```

Code block 02

```
<div class="pstinfo">
    <!-- info is here -->
</div>
<span class="plsign">+</span>

<script>
$("div.pstinfo").hide();
$("span.plsign").click(function () {
  $("div.pstinfo").stop().slideToggle("slow");
});
</script>
```

Try this code and Update the result :)

Comment: It seems to work every second post, for some reason...(on the same preview http://noitsnotitsnotokay.tumblr.com/)
the odd posts show and hide a small line :S

Comment: it seems to be some sort of Tumblr glitch, though, because it works in the preview when I customize it! so yay :D

Comment: Used your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DL6QZ/3/) added some content. But can not reproduce your problem. Possibly another error in your or the code of tumblr?

Comment: no its not a error in Tumbler !
The problem with your jquery events calling !
here you have to use a method like .parent() .find() !

Comment: here found some solution for visible problem of slideToggles

**add height:200px !important; to the .pstinfo class!**

Then it will be visible on click event !
Then see the output with above code & update !

Comment: It seems that the height didn't help :S (also sorry for the disappearance, I had a class)
how would I use the .parent()?

Comment: Looks like this worked in the preview, too, but not in the main...how strange.

Comment: <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("div.pstinfo").hide('slow');
$("span.plsign").click(function() {
$(this).parent().children("div.pstinfo").stop().slideToggle(500); });
});
</script>